# How to allow window resize after calling QMainWindow.setFixedSize?

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, resize, qmainwindow

I would like to know how to allow the user to resize the window after calling `QMainWindow.setFixedSize` ?
For example, he click a button, that execute a function that re-enable the window resizement.
I checked on the internet, but I didn't found anything... I tried `QMainWindow.setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy.Maximum,QSizePolicy.Minimum)`, but that didn't work... Any idea ?

Thank you !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [`setFixedSize()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#setFixedSize) documentation:

> To remove constraints, set the size to [QWIDGETSIZE_MAX](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#QWIDGETSIZE_MAX).

So, the solution is to do the following:

```
self.setFixedSize(16777215,16777215)
```